# Render a partail view using jquery for a click event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to print data entered in an input form using a partial view and I am getting the output. But, in the source tab in Developers tool I see that the code of my PartailView(_PartailStudent) in being embedded under  tag which is throwing an error in the console tab. I need to know a better way to render the PartialView.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("hitting ready");
        $("#btn_std").click(function(){
            console.log("Hello");
            @Html.Partial("_PartialStudent", Model)
        });
        $("#btn_back").click(function(){
           document.location = '@Url.Action("Index","Student")';
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Button tag:**

```
<tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" id="btn_std" value="Submit" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" id="btn_back" value="Back" />
            </td>
</tr>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Student
        public ActionResult Student()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Student(Student form)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                return PartialView("_PartialStudent", form);
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

> Console error : Student:88 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: fine read the code of your partial view you might be adding extra char in the file by mistake.

Comment: @AnkushKhemka it's not possible this  C# code with javascript you need to manage Ajax call with help to render partial view.

Comment: What do you mean by print data?  Do you mean place it on your page somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a guess about what your input form is. 
I don't know what your student class is so I'm going to pretend it is this

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I think something like this will get you close to what you are after

```
@model Student
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "studentForm" }))
{
    <input type="text" name="Name" value="@Model.Name" />
}

<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" id="btn_std" value="Submit" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" id="btn_back" value="Back" />
    </td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("hitting ready");
        $("#btn_std").click(function(){
            console.log("Hello");
            var $form = $("#studentForm");
            var url = $form.attr("action");
            var type = $form.attr("method");

            var ajaxOptions = {
                url: $form.attr("action"),
                type: $form.attr("method"),
                data: $form.serialize()
            }

            $.ajax(ajaxOptions).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });

        });
        $("#btn_back").click(function(){
           document.location = '@Url.Action("Index","Student")';
        });
    });
</script>
```

The data in the ajax done method will be the contents of the partial view. It isn't clear what you want done with it so I have console.logged it but you could use the jQuery replaceWith method to put it on the page.